# Как показать разные Модули в одном ContentControl с использованием Prism и MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Есть некое окно(WPF) с RibbonBar(syncfusion), так же в окне присутствует ContentControl для показа Prism Modules используя Unity. При старте программы модуль вполне себе нормально показывается но, ума не приложу, как при нажатии кнопки в RibbonBar, убрать с вида один модуль и вместо него показать другой. Спасибо!
PS: думаю способ должен быть через Binding
XAML:

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{Binding RegionName}"/>
```

C#:

```
public string RegionName
    {
        get { return regionName; }
        set
        {
            regionName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RegionName");
        }
    }
```

При таком способе RegionName меняется
C#:

```
public void WorldsButtonEventHandler()
    {
        RegionName = "SomeRegion";
    }
```

OnPropertyChanged срабатывает но модуль не появляется.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это делается так - создается два свойства

1. Коллекция возможных вьюмоделей
2. Выбранная модель(`UserControl`)

Биндинг на выбранную модель(`<ContentControl Content="{Binding 2.свойство}"/>`).

По нажатию кнопки(или чего-нибудь ещё) происходит изменение выбранной модели.